# Folder not naming properly after creation

Tags: c++, function, directory, naming

I have a C++ function createFolder (the symbols before the comments are for the better comments addon in vscode):

```cpp
void createFolder(const char *dir, const char *foldername)
{
    // ! Checking to see if the folder already exists
    if (hasFolder(dir, foldername))
        return;

    // ? Full directory
    char buffer[sizeof(dir) + sizeof(foldername) - 2];

    strncpy(buffer, dir, sizeof(buffer));
    strncpy(buffer, foldername, sizeof(buffer));

    // ? Creating folder
    int success = mkdir(buffer);

    // ! Checking to see if folder creation worked
    if (success == -1)
        std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
}
```

For some reason if I try to create a folder with a name longer than 6 characters long, it adds this weird bit to the end `st.t12ÀÌ6u`

Here is the code i'm using to test this out:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // This will work fine
    createFolder("./", "123456");
    
    // This adds the weird "st.t12ÀÌ6u" part
    createFolder("./", "1234567");

    return 0;
}
```

I doubt it has anything to do with the `char buffer[]` part of the code as I have tested this individually and it works just fine.

Comment: `sizeof(dir)` is the size of the `char*` pointer (usually 4 or 8), not the length of the string `dir` points to. As  a result, most lilkely `buffer` is too small for the string you are trying to put into it, and you end up with a buffer overrun. Do yourself a favor, use `std::string` for your string manipulation needs.

Comment: If `sizeof` did what you thought, why are you subtracting 2? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try using std::strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Tandetnik suggested using `std::string` instead of `const char *`. This seemed to work.